# How do I automatically pull an .xlsx file generated by a link when clicked at that time? There is no constant URL. Details below

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to be able to automatically pull the file located on this page into a google sheet:

https://netapps.ocfl.net/CETitleViolationSearch/

It generates when you click "here" in "click here." at the bottom.

If you copy link address for that you get: javascript:__doPostBack('lnkSubmit','')

Guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Sincerely there is no much you can do. Just upload it to Google Drive and convert it to google sheets format. Could you maybe explain what is your workflow and desired output? Like clicking the link and getting the file directly in Google Sheets? Upload the downloaded file directly as a google sheets? What could work in this situation?

Comment: The only solution I know in this situation is manual upload or automation software that pretends to be a user and downloads the file to your drive.

Comment: That's crazy to me. With google scripts I am able to perform query functions on a 30mb zipped .txt file, although it has a static URL.